# edittext.getText().getString() is always empty

Tags: java, android, input, android-edittext

I am working on an notes app for android. I am trying to save the text the user wrote to EditText into a variable `inputText` . But the variable is always `""`. I am really confused. Any ideas? (The problem is probbably in `Setphase2` method.)

```
package vitosoft.notes;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final int[] phase = {1};
    final String[] text_encode = {""};
    final Button r_button = findViewById(R.id.rightButton);
    final Button l_button = findViewById(R.id.leftButton);
    final EditText input = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final TextView task = findViewById(R.id.task);

    r_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (phase[0] == 1) {
                phase[0] = 2;
                text_encode[0] = Setphase2(r_button, l_button, task, input);
            }
        }
    });

    l_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (phase[0] == 2) {
                phase[0] = 1;
                Setphase1(text_encode[0], r_button, l_button, task, input);

            }
        }
    });
    }

public String Setphase2(Button r,Button l,TextView t,EditText i) {
    i.setText("");
    r.setText(R.string.upload);
    l.setText(R.string.edit);
    t.setText(R.string.key_task);
    String inputText = i.getText().toString();
    Log.d("UserText", "Entry text is:" + inputText);
    i.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
    return inputText;
}
public void Setphase1 (String original, Button r,Button l,TextView t,EditText i){
    i.setText(original);
    r.setText(R.string.encode);
    l.setText(R.string.decode);
    t.setText(R.string.entry_task);
    i.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

}
}
```

Comment: You are setting `i.setText("");` so it is empty

Comment: Okay, I am really ***. I am so sorry for that stupid question, I am just blind! Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android edittext.getText().toString() is always empty.. Because you assigning it as empty.

```
public String Setphase2(Button r,Button l,TextView t,EditText i) {
    i.setText(""); // See this line**************
    r.setText(R.string.upload);
    l.setText(R.string.edit);
    t.setText(R.string.key_task);
    String inputText = i.getText().toString();
    Log.d("UserText", "Entry text is:" + inputText);
    i.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
    return inputText;
}
```

Remove the following line in the above method.

```
i.setText("");
```

Comment: Okay, I am really ***. I am so sorry for that stupid question, I am just blind! Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling method i.setText(""); at the beginning of Setphase2 method.

Comment: Okay, I am really ***. I am so sorry for that stupid question, I am just blind! Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

In the `Setphase2` method

```
i.setText("");
r.setText(R.string.upload);
l.setText(R.string.edit);
t.setText(R.string.key_task);
String inputText = i.getText().toString();
```

You are setting `i` to `""` and then setting `inputText` equal to `i`.

Comment: Okay, I am really ***. I am so sorry for that stupid question, I am just blind! Sorry!